# Telerik Blazor GridCommandButton not working

Tags: kendo-ui, blazor, telerik, kendo-grid, telerik-grid

I have been working with Blazor and Telerik and I seem to have the grid showing data, the css looks fine,  but mostly using code from the Telerik samples and I'm surprised at how much effort it is taking to figure out why the GridCommandButton does not seem to trigger anything like it does online in the Repl

```
<TelerikGrid Data=@MyData EditMode="@GridEditMode.Inline" Pageable="true" Height="400px"
             OnAdd="@AddHandler" OnUpdate="@UpdateHandler" OnEdit="@EditHandler" OnDelete="@DeleteHandler" OnCreate="@CreateHandler" OnCancel="@CancelHandler">
    <GridToolBarTemplate>
        <GridCommandButton OnClick="AddHandler" Command="Add" Icon="@SvgIcon.Plus">Add Employee</GridCommandButton>
    </GridToolBarTemplate>
    <GridColumns>
        <GridColumn Field=@nameof(SampleData.ID) Title="ID" Editable="false" />
        <GridColumn Field=@nameof(SampleData.Name) Title="Name" />
        <GridCommandColumn>
            <GridCommandButton Command="Save" Icon="@SvgIcon.Save" ShowInEdit="true">Update</GridCommandButton>
            <GridCommandButton Command="Edit" Icon="@SvgIcon.Pencil">Edit</GridCommandButton>
            <GridCommandButton Command="Delete" Icon="@SvgIcon.Trash">Delete</GridCommandButton>
            <GridCommandButton Command="Cancel" Icon="@SvgIcon.Cancel" ShowInEdit="true">Cancel</GridCommandButton>
        </GridCommandColumn>
    </GridColumns>
</TelerikGrid>
```